# Reading streaming data using Google Cloud Dataflow SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am working on an IOT application where I need to read streaming data from a PubSub topic. I want to read this data using Google Cloud Dataflow SDK. I am using Java 1.8

I am using the trial version of Google Cloud Platform. When I was using PubSubIO.Read method to read the streaming data, I was getting errors in the log file that my project does not have enough CPU quota to run the app.

So I want to read the streaming data using Google Cloud Dataflow SDK.

Can someone please let me know where can I find complete examples of reading the streaming data using Google Cloud Dataflow SDK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PubsubIO.Read is the correct way. Please post the errors you were getting, and ideally your job ID.

Comment: (bdaaec3d0f58e13): Workflow failed. Causes: (50ffe37e5aed6b7): Project xxxxxxxx has insufficient quota(s) to execute this workflow with 3 instances in region us-central1. Quota summary (available/required): 80/3 instances, 8/12 CPUs, 2048/1260 disk GB, 1024/0 SSD disk GB, 100/1 instance groups, 50/1 managed instance groups, 100/1 instance templates, 23/3 in-use IP addresses.

Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas about requesting more quota.

Comment: Please find the error message from the logs above. Kindly let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

A number of complete examples are available in Cloud Dataflow documentation under [Complete Examples](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/all-examples) and, linked from there, on Github, also under [Complete Examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete).

According to your error message, you indeed have not enough CPU quota to run the default 3x 4-threaded (`n1-standard-4`) workers. The [CPU quota for Google Cloud trial](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/free-trial-quotas) is 8 CPUs.

You can [configure your job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) to require fewer CPUs, e.g. by using fewer workers (e.g. `--numWorkers=1`) or a different machine type (`--workerMachineType=n1-standard-1`)